# PowerShell: Cannot find proper .ctor when the .ctor has only one argument of type List<T>

Tags: powershell, syntax, constructor, parameter-passing

It seems that there is a bug in the O-O support in **PowerShell**.

When instantiating an object of a class with a constructor that accepts a **List< T >** and **this is the only parameter**, PowerShell cannot find a proper constructor.

Code sample:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(
        #[int]$i,
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] $theparams)
    {

    }
}

$parameters = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string];
$foo = New-Object MyClass -ArgumentList @(
    #1,
    $parameters)
```

> Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type MyClass.

Uncommenting the `[int]` parameter makes it work fine.

**Workaround**: since Powershell doesn't handle visibility of the members, if the parameter is used to assign a class member then you can directly assign it outside the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>To avoid the pitfall discussed here, consider using the class' static `::new()` method (PSv5+), as demonstrated in [Maximilian Burszley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307753/45375).</sup>

Note: **The following applies not just to `New-Object`, but to *all* cmdlets that accept an array of arguments via a single parameter** (typically named `-ArgumentList` / alias `-Args`), **notably also `Invoke-Command` and `Start-Job`.**

<sup>To find all commands that have an `-ArgumentList` parameter, run `Get-Help * -Parameter ArgumentList`</sup>

---

**To pass a collection *as a whole* as *the only argument* to `New-Object`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter, you must *wrap it in an aux. array* using `,`, the array-construction operator**<sup>[1]</sup>:

```bash
New-Object MyClass -ArgumentList (, $parameters)
```

Without the wrapper, the elements of collection `$parameters` would be interpreted as *individual* constructor arguments.

However, **if there is *at least one other explicitly enumerated argument*, the wrapping is no longer needed**:

```bash
# With `[int] $i` as the 1st constructor argument defined:
New-Object MyClass -ArgumentList 1, $parameters
```

The reason is that `1, $parameters` constructs an array in a manner that *implicitly* passes `$parameters` as a *single* argument: `$parameters` *as a whole* becomes the array's 2nd argument.

---

---

<sup>[1] Note that `@($parameters)` would *not* work, because `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator, is a *no-op* (loosely speaking) if the expression already *is* an array.

I say loosely speaking, because `@(...)` actually *rebuilds* the input collection as a (new) `[object[]]` array - which has performance implications and can result in a different collection type.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the constructor syntax since you're on PSv5 anyways.  This worked in my testing and there may be something funky going on with `New-Object`:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] $Params) { }
}

[MyClass]::new([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new())
```

Comment: +1 for a good alternative, but note that while `New-Object`'s behavior may be slightly surprising at first, it is as designed: `-ArgumentList` is declared as `Object[]` to receive _all_ constructor arguments, so passing a collection as the only argument treats the elements of that collection as _individual_ constructor arguments.

Comment: @mklement0 `List<T>` can just go away `;)`