# Passing an Array Parameter Value

Tags: powershell, arguments, new-object

I have some code in PowerShell (below) to call the `System.Guid` constructor with a byte array (`byte[]`) as the only parameter.

The C# equivalent of this code is:

```
byte[] binaryData = userObj["ADGuid"].Value;
Guid adid = new System.Guid(binaryData);
```

This is my PowerShell code.  It interprets the items array as individual parameters.  How do I need to adjust this code?

```
[byte[]]$binaryData = $uo["ADGuid"].Value                 
$adid = new-object System.Guid -ArgumentList $binaryData
```

Here is a screenshot of the error message:

[image: PowerShell Error Message]

Comment: Could you add the definition of $uo ?

Comment: @ExcèsRefusé --- just FYI the object `$uo` is of type `[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is treating the array of bytes as a list of 16 individual parameters and trying to find a constructor for `System.Guid` that accepts that many, which it can't do because [there isn't one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-6.0).

If you want to pass a single parameter which just happens to be an array of 16 bytes you need to wrap it in a "sacrificial array" so PowerShell only sees one parameter for the constructor...

```
$adid = new-object System.Guid -ArgumentList @(, $binaryData)
```

In this case, the single parameter is an array of bytes, which it *can* find a constructor overload for (i.e. [`public Guid (byte[] b);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-guid-ctor(system-byte()))).

Comment: I've never heard of the `sacrificial array` -- i like it... its a bit clunky but it gets the job done

Comment: It’s not an official term - it’s one I heard in passing a while ago and it kind of stuck in my head :-). If you want a better description you might want to look at one of the answers in the duplicate questions - this one is pretty thorough… https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307779/3156906